# Service not triggering modal while using error interceptor

Tags: angular

I am working on building a service that intercepts errors from HTTP requests. I can get it to log and a handle a few errors here and there, but have not succeeded in what I am ultimately trying to do.

My goal is to have it open a dialog window when the error is finished being handled by the interceptor. This dialog window is triggered via  service, and subscribed to via a component.

Here is my setup.

**component.ts**

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private errorService: ErrorService, 
        private modal: NgbModal
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.errorService.errorTrigger$.subscribe(res => {
            // use this to open the modal
            let modalRef = this.modal.open(ModalComponent, options);
            modalRef.componantInstance.errorMessage = res.error.message;
        });
    }
}
```

**interceptor.ts**

```
export class ErrorIntercept implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) { } 
    intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let err = null;
        return next.handle(request)
            .pipe(
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    switch(error.status){
                       case 401:
                       case 403:
                       case 500:
                          err = error;
                       break;
                    }    
                    return throwError(errorMessage);
                }),
                finalize(() => this.errorService.triggerError(err))
            )
    }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
export class ErrorService {
    private errorTrigger = new BehaviorSubject<ErrorEvent>(null);
    public errorTrigger$ = this.errorTrigger.asObservable(); 
    triggerError(error: ErrorEvent) {
        this.errorTrigger.next(error);
    }
}
```

What I'm running into is that when my program is operational and I make an HTTP request, the service never triggers and I can never open my modal. Why is this occurring? Perhaps I do not understand error handling as much as I thought I did.

Comment: could you provide a piece of logic of how you open the dialog? the reason of error could be that Angular change detection doesn't see your changes and therefore doesn't show you dialog as opened

Comment: A complete minimal example as a stackblitz would help tremendously. There are many unknowns i what you posted: is the interceptor provided, how are the services provided, etc.

Comment: @Andrei this has been done